# Condition makes the function integrable for polynomial

Tags: integration

> $$\int_{B(0,1)} {dx \over |x|^a} < \infty \iff a<n$$
>   Where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

I tried letting $x_i=\max \{ x_1, ... x_n\}$ and substituted the integral with inequality but it didn't helped.

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)   on $\mathbb{R}^n$ so the volume element is 
$$dV = r^{n-1} \sin^{n-2}(\phi_1)\sin^{n-1}(\phi_2) \dots  \sin(\phi_{n-2}) d\phi_1  d\phi_2\dots d\phi_{n-1}$$

So your integral is convergent if and only if $\int\limits_{r=0}^1  r^{n-1-\alpha } dr < \infty $ which means $n-1-\alpha> -1  $